# How to style CSS Mobile Optimization for Grid Items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm working on a site and have this product grid that I want to condense down to mobile. Is it possible, using only CSS and not having to comment out or hide html, to go from this first image on desktop to look like the second image on mobile? [original desktop layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdeLf.png) [desired mobile layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcL9n.png). currently, the images stay the same and condense down to 1 column on mobile with the image above the text and subtext. I would essentially prefer the image to the left and the text to the right to fit more of the category groupings on a mobile page for a better user experience. Is there a way to do this in just CSS?

I can do this by building out entirely new code for mobile only, but that will slow page load time, having to load images but keep them hidden at certain sizes which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Use media queries, you won't have to comment out, you'll just be removing items as the screen gets smaller, and you can adjust the positioning of the elements as well.

Comment: @AJAnde Thank you! What would that CSS look like? div id for that section is "solutions"

Comment: Well if you could provide some of your code, I'd be happy to give an example.